# Session window in Reactor

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

Apache Flink and Kafka Streams have the concept of a session window.

The window is defined based on the time between two consecutive messages from the same key.
If the time between two consecutive messages is less than the specified session gap, then the messages are considered to belong to the same session.
If the gap is larger than the session gap, the window is emitted and a new window is started.

It is trivial to configure a session window in both Flink and KafkaStreams:

- `.window(EventTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(10)))`
- `.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofMinutes(5)).grace(Duration.ofSeconds(30)))`

I tried to do the same thing with Reactor, but I cannot find a way to do it, probably my knowledge of Reactor is too limited.

I see that Reactor has multiple variations of the window operation, like windowWhile, windowUntil, windowUntilChanged.
But the predicates that they take as arguments evaluate only the current key, not the gap to the previous key.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can answer my own question, after reading through the Reactor docs and searching for the relevant operator.

The session window functionality can be achieved using the 2 operators **bufferUntilChanged** or **windowUntilChanged** with the following signatures:

- `<V> Flux<List<T>> bufferUntilChanged(Function<? super T,? extends V> keySelector, BiPredicate<? super V,? super V> keyComparator)`
- `<V> Flux<Flux<T>> windowUntilChanged(Function<? super T,? extends V> keySelector, BiPredicate<? super V,? super V> keyComparator)`

The first **Function** argument selects the key that should be compared.
In case of a session window, this key should be the event time stored in the event.

The second **BiPredicate** argument compares the current key with the previous key.
In case of a session window, I can subtract the previous event time from the current event time and if the difference is larger than a certain interval, I can return either true and add the current item to the ongoing buffer/window or return false and emit the ongoing window and start a new one.